# How to implement aurelia-i18n along with webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

We need to implement aurelia-i18n package using webpack. Please specify the webpack.config.js configurations

package.json

```
    {

"dependencies":
 {
"aurelia-bootstrapper-webpack": "^1.0.0",
"aurelia-event-aggregator": "^1.0.0",
"aurelia-framework": "^1.0.1",
"aurelia-history-browser": "^1.0.0",
"aurelia-loader-webpack": "^1.0.3",
"aurelia-logging-console": "^1.0.0",
"aurelia-templating-binding": "^1.0.0",
"aurelia-templating-resources": "^1.0.0",
"aurelia-templating-router": "^1.0.0"
},
"devDependencies":
 {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.52",
    "aurelia-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "bluebird": "^2.9.2",
   "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
   "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
   "toastr": "^2.1.2",
"ts-node": "^1.7.2",
"webpack": "^1.14.0"
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is totally correct with SO guidelines, but instead of describing every detail about the webpack configuration I'd instead like to link to the official documentation, which will likely be more up-to-date than any quesiton.

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/i18n/latest/i18n-with-aurelia/2